# XML validation based on dtd

Tags: xml

The paragraph below is from this source http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Definition

"Note that any valid SGML or XML document that references an external subset in its DTD, or whose body contains references to parsed external entities declared in its DTD (including those declared within its internal subset), may only be partially parsed but cannot be fully validated by validating SGML or XML parsers in their standalone mode (this means that these validating parsers will not attempt to retrieve these external entities, and their replacement text will not be accessible)."

Can someone explain this to me in simpler terms?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i got it, it only means that if the document is a standalone one, it will only be partially parsed and not fully because external references will be ignored